# Label referring problem

Tags: errors, cross-referencing, characters

I'm new here and new user of LaTeX I'm trying to write my PhD, intermediate reports with it and I am facing some problems.
I tried to look on the internet for 2 weeks, but found no answer to my problem (or maybe I'm not getting everything I read).
I'm posting the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (MiKTeX 2.8)
entering extended mode
("E:/Rapport/Rapport TeX/Exemples/ModeleRapportStageLatex/Global.tex"
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, german, ngerman, german-x-2009-06-19, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, french,
 greek, italian, russian, turkish, ukenglish, farsi, loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\base\report.cls"
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty"
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*

("C:\Documents and Settings\karoui\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.8\tex\latex\arabi\
bblopts.cfg") ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\generic\babel\frenchb.ldf"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\generic\babel\babel.def")
*************************************
* Local config file frenchb.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\generic\babel\frenchb.cfg")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\carlisle\scalefnt.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("E:\Rapport\Rapport TeX\Exemples\ModeleRapportStageLatex\ucs.sty"
("E:\Rapport\Rapport TeX\Exemples\ModeleRapportStageLatex\uni-global.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
("E:\Rapport\Rapport TeX\Exemples\ModeleRapportStageLatex\utf8x.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\ltxmisc\url.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Documents and Settings\karoui\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.8\tex\latex\listin
gs\listings.sty"
("C:\Documents and Settings\karoui\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.8\tex\latex\listin
gs\lstmisc.sty")
("C:\Documents and Settings\karoui\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.8\tex\latex\listin
gs\listings.cfg")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\graphics\lscape.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\tools\multicol.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\base\makeidx.sty")
Writing index file Global.idx
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\graphics\color.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg"))
("C:\Documents and Settings\karoui\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.8\tex\latex\setspa
ce\setspace.sty"
Package: `setspace' 6.7 <2000/12/01>
) ("E:\Rapport\Rapport TeX\Exemples\ModeleRapportStageLatex\Global.aux"

LaTeX Warning: Label `image_EFA' multiply defined.


LaTeX Warning: Label `image_EFA' multiply defined.


LaTeX Warning: Label `image_EFA' multiply defined.


LaTeX Warning: Label `image_EFA' multiply defined.


LaTeX Warning: Label `image_courbe' multiply defined.


LaTeX Warning: Label `image_courbe' multiply defined.


LaTeX Warning: Label `image_courbe' multiply defined.


LaTeX Warning: Label `image_courbe' multiply defined.


LaTeX Warning: Label `image_courbe' multiply defined.


LaTeX Warning: Label `image_courbe' multiply defined.


LaTeX Warning: Label `image_courbe' multiply defined.


LaTeX Warning: Label `image_courbe' multiply defined.


LaTeX Warning: Label `image_courbe' multiply defined.


LaTeX Warning: Label `image_courbe' multiply defined.


LaTeX Warning: Label `image_courbe' multiply defined.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \unhbox 
l.81 \newlabel{image_crit\IeC {\`e}re}{{4.2}{26}}

?
```

So I hope someone can help me.
I removed all labels by putting `%` before them.
I removed the whole text.
Nothing changes, I still get the same error.

Comment: Please show your minimal code.

Comment: @user2924: Please try and use some punctuation and capitalization. If your question is easily readable, then the probability of getting good answers increases!

Comment: I received a similar error with `\unhbox` in a LaTeX file. The error was resolved when I commented this line: `\usepackage[strings]{underscore}` in that file.

Answer (score 10):

Don't use chars with accents or commands in the `\label`-argument. The label is only an identification key and should be a simple ascii string.

Then delete the .aux-file (it is from the previous run and will still contain faulty labels) and try again.

Comment: I used 1.1.1 or 2.2.2 and it works fine.

Answer (score 7):

do not use spcial characters in labels, in your case use `\label{image-critere}`